# MongoDb updateOne have a maxTimeMS option?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Using MongoDB 3.0.14

using node driver, is maxTimeMS: QUERY_TIME a valid option for updateOne? Or is there a likewise option I can use in the below code?

Right now, when I induce a error by turning off mongodb daemon, I get `MongoError: failed to reconnect after 30 attempts with interval 1000 ms`

```
var QUERY_TIME = 500;

TempUsers.prototype.add = function(body, token) {
  const user = { "email" : body.email };

  return this.collection.updateOne(user,
    { $set: {
      // TO DO - ADD PHONE NUMBER
      "token": token,
      "createdAt": new Date(),
      }
    },
    {
      writeConcern: true,
      maxTimeMS: QUERY_TIME,
      upsert: true
    }
  );
};

module.exports = TempUsers;
```

Comment: is Mongodb up to date?

Comment: I think you need to valid the data before you trying to insert it to DB instead of catch an error